# Copy objects between class loaders

Tags: jakarta-ee, classloader

My task is to **copy objects** from the `ClassB` of `ClassLoaderB` into the `ClassA` of the `ClassLoaderA`. `ClassLoaderA` is a child of the `ClassLoaderB`.

I tried to use serialization and saved the class `ClassB`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
oos.writeObject( ClassB );
```

Next step would be to read this object into `ClassA` of the `ClassLoaderA`. How can I do that?

**UPD:**

Here is how the object is deserialized:

```
    //Resurrection
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray() );
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( bais );
    try {
        Object b1 = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        ClassA a1 = (ClassA) b1;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is that there is a ClassCastException in line:

```
ClassA a1 = (ClassA) b1;
```

Comment: You can copy on object ClassB into a variable of ClassA only if ClassB extends ClassA, otherwise you will have compile errors or ClassCastExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the simplest way is to expose an RMI method from classloader A and then call it from classloader B, passing the object as argument.

If you want to read the serialized file:

```
package com.mkyong.io;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Deserializer{

   public static void main (String args[]) {

       Deserializer deserializer = new Deserializer();
       Address address = deserializer.deserialzeAddress();
       System.out.println(address);
   }

   public Address deserialzeAddress(){

       Address address;

       try{

           FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("c:\\address.ser");
           ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
           address = (Address) ois.readObject();
           ois.close();

           return address;

       }catch(Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
       } 
   } 
}
```

The code has been taken from: 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-an-object-from-file-in-java/

---

**Update**

You can copy on object ClassB into a variable of ClassA only if ClassB extends ClassA, otherwise you will have compile errors or ClassCastExceptions:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{

   ...

}
```

This happends because the serialized file contains not only data, but also information about the Class that has been serialized.

I suppose that you are a former C / C++ programmer, because in those languages you don't have errors in this case.

Comment: Ok, yes, I tried deserialization, but it turns out that the object (`Address address` in the example) becomes one of the parent ClassLoaderB. I probably need reflection or something..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you post the code of the classes that you are using to serialize and deserialize?

Comment: @DaniilLuzin you can create an interface InterfaceC that is implemented by ClassA and by ClassB and then you can write: `InterfaceC i = (InterfaceC)ois.readObject();`